# Convert Query to Eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

How to make that query with eloquent

```
SELECT employees.first_name, companies.name FROM employees
JOIN companies ON employees.company_id = companies.id
```

My relationships

```
public function employees()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Employee::class);
}

public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}
```

I fetching the name with a given ID, but how can I find it for all. Or maybe I am thinking wrong

```
$employee = $employee->all()->find($id)->company->name;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assumed your `employees` Model name as `Employee` and `companies` Model name as `Company`

```
$employees = Employee::with('company')->get();

if(!empty($employees)){
    foreach($employees as $employee){
        echo $employee->first_name;
        echo $employee->company->name;
    }
}
```

If you want to search per id then you may do as below.

```
$employee = Employee::with('company')->find($id);
echo $employee->company->name;
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for edited the answer @N69S but without `with` you can access by using eager load `$employee->company->name;`

Comment: @DilipHirapara it was just to give the example so he knows he can do that in a find query.

Comment: Got your point @N69S :) I appreciate you focused on the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$employee = Employee::where('employees.id',$id)
            ->join('companies','companies.id','=','employees.company_id')
             ->select('employees.first_name', 'companies.name')
              ->first();
```

Comment: I appreciate, Great start @yogesh, but OP ask with eloquent.

Comment: Thanks  I thought this way it's much better

Answer (score 0):

Firs Of all this is very bad practice:

`$employee = $employee->all()->find($id)->company->name;`

This returns all employee collection and then searches id in it. You can simply use `Employee::find($id)`

Now about your query, as I guess your company model has many employee and if you want to find all company employees you have to do like that:

```
$company->employees()->select('first_name')->get(); // Collection of Employee
```

If you want to get specific company employee with employee id you can do:

```
$company->employees()->select('first_name')->where('id', $id)->first(); // null or Employee
```